# Is exists the easy way for switching the target XML-files of the documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, sandcastle, xml-documentation

On the base of the XML-comments I generate the documentation by Sandcastle. I want to generate the English and Russian version of the documentation.

My XML-files `Magic.doc.enu.xml` and `Magic.doc.rus.xml` are located in the same project (the target dll).

For example I can do it through such ugly way:

```
namespace HelloDocs {

#if ENU
    /// <include file='Magic.doc.enu.xml' 
    /// path='Documentation/Member[@Name="HelloDocs.Magic"]/*'/>
#elif RUS
    /// <include file='Magic.doc.rus.xml' 
    /// path='Documentation/Member[@Name="HelloDocs.Magic"]/*'/>
#endif
    public class Magic {
#if ENU
        /// <include file='Magic.doc.enu.xml' 
        /// path='Documentation/Member[@Name="HelloDocs.Magic.Foo()"]/*'/>
#elif RUS
        /// <include file='Magic.doc.rus.xml' 
        /// path='Documentation/Member[@Name="HelloDocs.Magic.Foo()"]/*'/>
#endif
        public void Foo() { }
    }
}
```

Can I do the switching of the XML-files without the ugly `#if\#elif\#endif` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I published its detailed description [here](http://bushman-andrey.blogspot.ru/2016/11/blog-post.html).